Trying to get the equivalent command for IoT hub
I'm trying to get the equivalent IoT hub command for
az iot central app show --name ${{ parameters.iotcName }} | ConvertFrom-Json

to get and print.
I tried changing the Iot central to Iot hub to make this command work.

az iot hub show --name MyIoTHub .
The az iot hub show command in Azure CLI is used to retrieve details about an IoT hub

az iot hub show --name HubName -g resourese grup name  | jq  JSON from by using jq

use like this     | jq '.name, .location, .properties.hostName, .sku.name'

The az iot hub show command in Azure CLI is used to retrieve details about an IoT hub,
az iot hub show --name <IoT Hub Name>

az iot hub show --name HubName -g resourese grup name 


to parse the JSON output of an Azure CLI command use jq.
using jq, you can extract specific fields


az iot hub show --name HubName -g resourese grup name | jq '.name, .location, .properties.hostName, .sku.name'


